# Smooth scrolling vertical text for progress

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I need to create a control that will show text progress on a splash screen (e.g. will display various modules loaded and status of start up). I'd like the control to show only the last 3 or 4 lines such that new text will push the previous text up in a smooth animated manner.

Should I be using the TextBox control for this or some other control? If someone is able to point me in the right direction then that will be great.

Comment: Smooth scrolling text is tough! If 'smoothness' is a requirement make sure what hardware it's a requirement on!

Comment: No time for a code example hence comment not answer, but have you considered using creating a custom control that derives from Canvas, containing 4x TextBlocks for lines and animating the Canvas.GetTop attached property?

Comment: You probably should be using TextBlocks (not TextBoxes). You can also use Storyboards to animate their position, as Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson described in his comment.

Comment: There are several examples of doing that on the net. Search for WPF marquee.

Comment: I'm not sure if these would work because I don't want it to behave like a normal marquee. I'd like the Textblock to always show the last 3 or 4 lines of text. It would only scroll up when more text is pushed into it so it makes room for it. I am going to use the UI to show modules that are being loaded so the text will slowly be added to it. Everything I have found until now is for marquee text which just flies right off the screen.

Comment: I also assume your list of controls and status is dynamic.  And you want it smooth.  Hopefully someone will have an answer for you but I don't don't know how to feed a story board dynamic data while it it is running and that is what is sounds like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this effect quite easily with a `ListBox`, your text as `ListBoxItem`s and a custom animated `Panel`. In short, the `Panel` adds `Transform` objects to each item's `RenderTransform` property, which allows you to animate the items movement to their positions.

See this very good [article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control) to find out how to create the animated `Panel`... of course, you'll have to write your custom code to arrange the items that way you want. Once you have your custom `Panel`, you can use it in a `ListBox` (assuming you have included a reference to the namespace your `Panel` is in) like so:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <YourXmlns:YourAnimatedStackPanelPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but you said you wanted to have it scroll one line at a time as another line is added.  How about using `ScrollViewer.LineUp`?  I know this extremely rough, but as an idea...

```
private void ScrollBox()
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        scrollbox.LineUp();
        textbox.Text += "/r/n Next Line";
    }
}
```